# Quarkus - Kafka Streams - How to pass through config options to underlying producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, quarkus

[Quarkus' Kafka-Streams extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-streams#the-pipeline-implementation) provides a convenient way to start a pipeline. Necessary configuration options for the stream application, e.g., `quarkus.kafka-streams.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`  must be inserted in the `application.properties` file for the encompassing project.

Quarkus also provides a pass-through option for a finer configuration. The documentation states:

> All the properties within the kafka-streams namespace are passed through as-is to the Kafka Streams engine. Changing their values requires a rebuild of the application.

With that, we can for example pass-through a custom timestamp extractor (or any other configuration property that related to the streams configuration)

```
...
kafka-streams.default.timestamp.extractor=my.custom.extractor.class
...
```

On startup, the Quarkus extension prints out that this config property is not known, however we can see that it was correctly passed-through since `my.custom.extractor.class` shows up in the automatically printed configuration of the stream application.

How can we pass-through options to the underlying Kafka producer and consumer and validate their usage? For example, I want to change the underlying producer's `max.request.size` and the consumer's `max.partition.fetch.bytes` properties.

The native Kafka Streams and the [old Quarkus approach](https://quarkus.io/blog/kafka-streams-applications-with-quarkus-and-microprofile/#the-quarkus-extension-for-kafka-streams) allow me to directly change the passed configuration object in code, e.g.,

```
streamsProperties.put(StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG), 6000000);
```

IMO this is dirty in Quarkusland and I would like to pass through all options via the `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass it using standard configuration for consumers and producers, prefixed with kafka-streams:

```
kafka-streams.consumer.$property
kafka-streams.producer.$property
```

Check -> https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-streams